# How to get previous year using PHP

Tags: php

How am I able to get the value of the previous year using PHP. Are there any predefined functions for it?

Comment: Whats the problem? `$previousYear = $year - 1;` or something like `$prevYear = date('Y', $timestamp) - 1;`

Comment: something like $prevYear = date('Y', $timestamp) - 1;

Answer (score 138, accepted):

try

```
echo date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));
```

Answer (score 16):

```
$year = date("Y");
$previousyear = $year -1;
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Comment: Binary operation "-" between string and 1 results in an error, you'll better to use `$year = (int)date("Y");
$previousyear = $year -1;`

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways, you can either take away the amount of seconds in a year from `time()` like so:

`$prevYear = date('Y', time() - 60*60*24*365 );`

Or if you'd prefer, use the PHPs clever `strtotime()` function:

`$prevYear = date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));`

Or even like others have said, if it's from todays year just do `date('Y') -1`

Comment: This  date('Y', time() - 60*60*24*365 ) should be used with care, because leap years will create problem.

Answer (score 6):

Shortest approach:

```
$lastYear = (int)date("Y") - 1;
```

Comment: Binary operation "-" between string and 1 results in an error, you'll better to use `$lastYear = (int)date("Y") - 1;`

Answer (score 3):

```
function adddate($vardate,$added)
{
$data = explode("-", $vardate);
$date = new DateTime();            
$date->setDate($data[0], $data[1], $data[2]);
$date->modify("".$added."");
$day= $date->format("Y-m-d");
return $day;    
}

echo "Example : " . adddate("2010-08-01","-1 year");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    echo date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));  //last year "2021"
    echo date("Y");                       //current year "2022"
    echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 year"));  //one year ago "2021-03-31"
    echo date("Y");                      //current date "2022-03-31"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can give a value of the input tag as :

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 year"));?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This thread needs an update.

Nowadays you would use the PHP date-time object and do something like this:

```
$lastYear = new DateTime();
$lastYear->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
echo $lastYear->format('Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the entire date exactly 1 year ago, including the month and year:

```
 <?php echo date("M d Y", strtotime("-1 year")); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
date('Y', strtotime('last year'));
```