# Current Year, and Previous Year in PHP

Tags: php

```
$a= date("Y");
```

What will be the data-type of `$a`: A number or a string? If it's a string, how do i get the previous year in PHP?

Comment: It is a variable.  You can use it as a string.  Or just subtract one from it.  `$last_year=date('Y')-1`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));  //last year "2013"
echo date("Y");                       //current year "2014"
```

[Also follow this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896345/how-to-get-previous-year-using-php)

[And this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747746/how-do-i-get-last-years-start-and-end-date)

Comment: So does, date("Y") gives the current year as a string?

Comment: @Ashutosh Yes,please use my both example in your php editor and see the result ,instead asking the answer.

Comment: @AshutoshSaboo:date("Y") give "2014"

Comment: Actually I have seen these two posts already earlier, and these were the one's that caused me a lot of confusion, because somewhere some have said that date("Y") gives the current year as a string, and somewhere some say that it gives the current year as a number (because somewhere arithmetic operations are performed and somewhere string operations are performed). So, which one is correct: date("Y") gives the current year as a string/number? That's the entire reason why I asked this question, PRECISELY.

Comment: so date("Y") gives the year as a string right? Can you also help me out on my other question: stackoverflow.com/questions/27692895/… . Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes:follow this link.it will gives you full details  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

```
  <?php
    echo $a= date("Y")-1;
   ?>
```

http://codepad.org/d0VjiyS5

its is not either string or number ,we can define it as string or else int using casting in php by using (int)

Comment: So, according to you date("Y") gives the current year "BY DEFAULT" in which data-type (number/string) , or does it give it both as a string and a number, and hence we can perform both arithmetic and string operations on date("Y")?

Comment: Can you also help me out on my other question: stackoverflow.com/questions/27692895/… . Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [relative date/time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

```
date('Y', strtotime('last year'));
```

Comment: So does, date("Y") give the current year as a string?

Comment: Can you also help me out on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692895/php-code-required-extracting-number-from-a-string?noredirect=1#comment43805401_27692895 . Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"));
```

Comment: @Rizier123: So does, date("Y") give the current year as a string?

Comment: @Rizier123: Can you also help me out on my other question: stackoverflow.com/questions/27692895/… . Thanks! :)